# Hosting a container hobby project

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hosting

I' m developing a hobby project which has;

- An Azure Microsoft SQL database
- An update process that gets data and puts in the database (for now run locally once a week)
- An API in Dotnet core 3.0 which reads from the database
- A NGINX frontend which is in Vue and reads from the API

The last two applications are containerized and I can run the docker image locally. I want this hosted (in the cloud) so I can show off my work and get experience with something like Kubernetes or any other orchestration tool.
What I'm looking for is a non-enterprise hosting platform which is free or a small monthly fee. I have an Azure developer budget but when I try the smallest Azure Kubernetes Service it still is going to cost me a lot.

Who has some advice on which hosting platform is working for their hobby projects?

Comment: Cloud is expensive :) If you need it just for a hobby project, I would go for cheap VPS and docker-compose on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up to do is just don't use K8s but stick to a container instance in Azure. I know it's a bit lame because I started out with K8s on my mind. Still, now I have got a relative cost-efficient solution with a private registry and two containers for under 10 euro.

Answer (score 0):

GCP has a fairly generous free tier, you could launch a 1-node cluster for free. It only has about a half a gigabyte of RAM though, you may find running both your app and SQL Server challenging. Heroku does offer a free-tier for their SQL database but it's Postgres not SQL Server.